# Best way to pass Data to third party Website?

Tags: marketing-cloud, third-party

this might be simple question and I am aware of how to pass Data in between Marketing Cloud via Ampscript.

But what would be the approach to pass Data to a Third Party Website via URL?

For example from an Email-Link to a personalized external Landingpage?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

In Marketing Cloud pass required fields as parameter on URL.

An option may be to pass key as a parameter on URL from Marketing Cloud, then on the external page do API request to Marketing Cloud to fetch additional data as required.